# Left Menu Bar in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[Screenshot of code that how to move to different screens through segue identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj5qZ.png).

I imported some files from an existing project on GitHub and made a left menu bar with the items: Home, About Us and Login.

When the user logs in using the "Login" menu bar item, I want title of the "Login" item to change to "Logout." The user should remain logged in until the user presses "Logout." When the user logs out, the item's title should change back to "Login."

Note: the items in left menu bar are static cells.

Comment: try this : https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

Comment: When you login success then set bool value for login success in userdefault and check if bool value is true then use ["","","logout"] and if false then use ["","","login"]

Comment: can u elaborate in detail please. @Bhupat Bheda

Comment: @omer can you show you code so i can modified them

Comment: reformatted and fixed some of the grammar to clarify the OP's requirements

Answer (score 0):

save your login `status(flag)` in `NSUSerDefaults`. When you logged in then save yes else no. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set title accordingly by checking that flag. and manage action(login or logout process) accordingly!

Comment: can u elaborate please I'm quite new i didn't understand. @Lion

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C

1) First save you login Status as below

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:true forKey:@"isLoggedIn"];
```

2) In cellForRow at indexPath write this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.row == YOUR TABLE CELL) {
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLoggedIn"]) {
         cell.lblMenuTitle.text = @"Log out";
        } else {
         cell.lblMenuTitle.text = @"Log In";
       }
     }
      [return cell];
    }
```

3) In DidSelect method of tableView write this code

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            if (indexPath.row == YOUR TABLE CELL) {
                if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLoggedIn"]) {
                     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:false forKey:@"isLoggedIn"];
                } else {
                     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:true forKey:@"isLoggedIn"];
                }
                [tableView reloadData];
            }
        }
```

4) And finally In Left menu class add code in viewWillAppear

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: im not using nsuserdefault im getting response and parsing it . what to write in the replacement of nsuserdefault? @Jaydeep

Comment: Yes, but while you get the login response, parse it and store flag like "isLoggedIn" into NSUserDefaults, after that when you call log out service remove the value from NSUserDefaults.
So it will work as status flag which indicate user logged in or not?. and same flag you can use into cellForRow method to manage Log in and Log out action.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't understand can explain in detail. @Jaydeep